# Creating an SQLite backup tool, need to know if .dump is atomic

Tags: sqlite

I'm needing to know if I'll need to take other measures to make sure the backup is complete (or at least not malformed), or if I can safely rely on .dump returning an up to date dump that I can later use to restore the database. For instance, if I run .dump at the same moment as someone else performing an insert/update, what happens?

Answer (score 2):

The `sqlite3` tool uses a transaction around the entire execution of the `.dump` command, so it's atomic.